# Powering cigarette lighter socket with remote start

Tags: electrical, remote-start

I've installed a remote car starter in Hyundai Elantra. When started remotely with no key in the ignition, the radio is off and cigarette lighter socket is off (it is back-lit though) I would like to have the cigarette lighter socket powered when remotely started (but unpowered when the engine is off)

Comment: The reason it does not work when remote started is due to the fact the key is still in the off position. Also, there is no way to tell you *how* to do what you are asking due to the lack of information. There are about 30 years worth of Elantras out there and thousands of different remote starts. I don't think it matters much anyway, as you'd have to completely re-wire your ignition system to get it to work the way you are talking about anyway.